# Round Up Double to Whole Number?

Tags: java, android

I have a double that contains the result of a calculation.

i.e 2.123 etc

Is there a simple way where i can round up this number to the
next number up  i.e 3

I have searched the forum, but only come up with how to round off to decimal places.

cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you checked [`Math.ceil(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) ?